# How can I transfer [content] from one page to another in MODx?

Tags: modx

There is a link on the page of the MODx site. By clicking on this link I turn to another page. I want to transfer all [content] from the first page to a new page and display it. How can I do this

Answer (score 2):

Use a TV with the @DOCUMENT binding or the [getField-Snippet](http://modx.com/extras/package/getfield). Both methods work for MODx Evolution.

On MODx-questions, please include whether your are using Evolution or Revolution, since the code base differs heavily, as so does the functionality.

Comment: Thanx feela, I just did not happen. In both proposed methods for solving my problem, I get the message "Unable to locate document" I use Evolution MODx

Comment: If i use [!GetField? &docid=`???` &field=`content`!] in second page, what i must set in &docid ? Second page can run from any of handreds pages.

Comment: @Astraport if there is a message "Unable to locate document", your document-id seems to be wrong. If you don't know what a doc-id within MODx is, you should refer to their documentation. Your second question: I don't know, what in your terminology is "first-" or "second-page". If you don't want to set a static doc-id, you can use another snippet within the GetField-snippet-call, to determine the document-id. This may be something like [UltimateParent](http://modx.com/extras/package/ultimateparent) or a self-created snippet, which may read the referer or a session-variable, to output a doc-id.

Comment: Solution: http://modxcms.com/forums/index.php/topic,64009.msg362155.html